# WI-FI module with at least 2MBps data rate

Tags: wifi

I want to Use a WI-FI module to connect my FPGA board to an android phone. I need 2 MByte per second data rate. So, can anyone offer me a proper wi-fi module? Unfortunately, most of them have serial interface and low data rate(Like [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-with-the-ESP8266-ESP-12/))

*In addition, Consider the cost!

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE! Please note that questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are considered off-topic.

Comment: Have a look at ATWILC1000

Answer (score 1):

There are many Wifi modules available with an SDIO interface, which enables speeds of several hundred Mbps (so you will probably be limited only by your Wifi link) and is much more straightforward to implement in an FPGA than USB or PCI-E.

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions:
1) An adapter for pc use. This can be USB or PCI-E based but might be a big hassle to implement.
2)An SPI based IC/module like the WF200 from Silicon Labs. This chip can hit 72.2 Mbps (they claim) dependent on the wifi version. This chip ain't expensive either ($3 or so) although I don't know what a premade module would cost.
I hope this helps

Comment: The WF200 doesn't support 72 Mbps in SPI mode, you'd need to use the SDIO port for that.

Comment: Ah yes, I did not notice that on the mouser page. You are right.

Comment: That said, SPI should be fast enough to meet OP's goal of 16 Mbps.